# Print values of all variable symbols referenced by current statement in gdb e.g. for assert(...) failures

Tags: gdb

I'm sure we've all looked at an `assert(foo || bar)` and wondered whether `foo` was false or `bar` was false.

Is there any way to convince `gdb` to examine such an expression - even when debugging a core file - and print the values of any symbols referenced by it? Even better, to do so recursively including macro-expansion when the executable was built with `-ggdb3`?

What I see now is something like:

```
#4  0x0000000000xxxxxx in Foo (....)
    at file:111
111     Assert(foo || bar);
```

and what I'm looking for is the ability to do:

```
(gdb) some_magic_command
  foo: (int32_t) 42
  bar: (int32_t) 0
```

as well, as if `echo <<varname>>:`, `ptype <<varname>>` and `p <<varname>>` was run for each variable that's directly referenced in the statement.

`Assert(foo || bar)` is obviously an arbitrary example statement to illustrate this. If I could just script `p foo` and `p bar`, there would be no question to ask.

The variables to identify and print are not necessarily in the same compilation unit, or in the same ELF executable. They could be externs, possibly with relocation. And of course they can only be shown if they can be resolved in the current context.

But surely there's some way to do this?

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: The magic command you appear to be looking for is `print foo` and `print bar`. If that doesn't work for you, you may want to clarify your question.

Comment: You can use `info locals` but it will output all locals, not only `foo` and `bar` on line 111.

Comment: @ks1322 Only if `foo` and `bar` are locals...

Comment: @EmployedRussian The above is an example. Consider how to derive and run `p foo` and `p bar` from `Assert(foo || bar);` and how to generalize that to variable-references in any arbitrary statement.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I updated the question. I hope that sufficiently clarifies the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to do this in gdb.  gdb does not know which variables are referenced by any given statement -- that information is not in the debug info.

You could conceivably achieve this by writing a command in Python that (1) extracts the text of the current line of code from the source, and (2) uses some technique to extract the variables from the text of the line.  However, this is difficult to do correctly, especially for C++.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess it'd be possible on a paused running executable by executing `p theStatement` - with the problem of repeating any effects from the statement. But not on a core.

Comment: So in sort, there's nothing in `DWARF` debuginfo that represents a given statement as any sort of parsetree or symbol-tree that could be used to supply this? I'm a little surprised, as I've noticed during my occasional and infrequent uses of MSVC's debugger that it's often capable of reporting things like the return value of a function that was an intermediate value in an expression passed as an argument to a call. I'd hoped GDB might be able to, if not derive the same details, then at least identify symbols that're visible in the current scope and report their values.

Comment: DWARF does list the variables in scope, but that isn't what this question asked for.  It generally limits its description of a statement to a line number and an address.  No parse tree info is available.  Showing variables in scope is easily done, but a given statement may refer to globals, data members, etc, possibly needing a namespace lookup, ...

Comment: Right - it knows what's in scope, but there's no way to know which in-scope variables were referenced directly by the current statement. Which is what I needed to know in the end, so thankyou.